Data augmentation for Bootstrapping low-variance data
I am working on local block bootstrapping of student right/wrong (0,1) data from an online learning tool. Note.  (local block bootstrapping creates moving blocks of responses but sets guardrails on how far away from the original block any replacement can be. It is a bootstrapping technique for trending time series)  Students tend to get very proficient by the end of their session (as one would hope), so the bootstrapping tend to over-estimate mean proficiency, so far as I can tell from a parametric bootstrap done on the same data.   How have others approached this problem?  If you have tried random response flipping (changing a random proportion of 1s to 0s), how did you set the parameters for doing this?   many thanks

Welcome to CV, Mary Ann.  Bootstrapping is, among other things, a method of bias correction.  Are you telling us that you haven't been able to correct your bootstrap results for bias?  It's unclear (at least to me) how improved proficiency would introduce any bias.  Perhaps you could explain what properties of these time series you are bootstrapping?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Twp sets of bootstrap analyses using student learning data (binary, 0 - right, 1 = wrong), first a parametric one, and then a a local block bootstrap, a technique created to keep trends together during resampling. The regular bootstrap where each record has an equal probability of selection was run as a control condition.
Given the number of "1"s in each students response, especially the latter part of the response string, bootstrapping may be producing samples that are representqative of the original sample but Not of the population.   How have folks worked with this situation in their datal
